How to identify an element has a closed shadow Root in it?
<div class="jest">
  #shadow-root(closed)
  <br>
  <input type="text">
</div>

How do I detect that this jest class has a closed shadow root in it.
Tried using .shadowRoot/ getRootNode, it returns null.
Can someone help.

Would something like //div[@class="jest"][contains(.,"shadow")] work for you?

There is no way to do it.
But from browser extension it is possible to check.
let shadowRoot = browser.dom.openOrClosedShadowRoot(
  element,    // HTMLElement
)

It returns shadowRoot object instance in both cases.
Another way is to patch original method and store shadowed elements in set.
const shadowedElements = new Set();
Element.prototype.attachShadow = (...args) => {
    shadowedElements.add(this)
    return original.apply(this, args)
}

if (shadowedElements.has(el)) {
  // caught
}

